# Tabs not visible after creating view tabs

Tags: views, 8, bootstrap-theme

I am trying to create view tabs and follow below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpuRdzyK3jI

but couldn't get any tabs displayed, only the results are displayed.

I am using Bootstrap Barrio sub theme.

I created a view with two pages

- fun (Menu named as "Hot")
- fun/fresh (Menu named as "Fresh")

When I access the url

http://localhost:8888/funnyplaceorg/web/fun

http://localhost:8888/funnyplaceorg/web/fun/fresh

I see the posts, but couldnt see the tabs.

[image]

Admin console for View pages

[image]

[image]

### Edit

1. Added more images.

Comment: Hey Rafee, what exactly is your question? And how can we reproduce your issue? Please update your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: Have you set the first Menu Tab as the default tab? I think you may need to set the path there to `fun/something`, and the `something` part will not be displayed on a default tab. The `fun` is actually the parent.

Comment: Yes, I did. I figured out there is a problem with Barrio sub theme (Not sure exactly), If I switch to Bartik theme, the tabs are displayed.